# yum package installation not installing all files

Tags: rpm, yum

I am trying to understand how yum and rpm work. If I run:

```
rpm -ql gstreamer.i686
```

then I get a list of the files that should be installed from that package:

```
/usr/bin/gst-feedback-0.10
/usr/bin/gst-inspect-0.10
/usr/bin/gst-launch-0.10
/usr/bin/gst-typefind-0.10
...
```

These files were indeed there upon the first install, however, I removed some of the ones in the /usr/bin/ dir like so:

```
rm -rf /usr/bin/gst-feedback-0.10
...
```

and now it doesn't matter if I run:

```
yum remove gstreamer.i686
yum install gstreamer.i686
```

OR

```
yum reinstall gstreamer.i686
```

the only file in that dir that is replaced is the first on the list "/usr/bin/gst-feedback-0.10". the rest do not come back. I have tried:

```
yum clean all
yum update
```

but same result. I am using a local repo created from an install disk due to connection constraints. I don't think the local repo is the problem since it installed fine the first time.

Note that yum does not fail on these install attempts. Also note that other listed folders/files from the `rpm -ql` command are reinstalled if removed, such as "/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/..."

What am I missing here? Shouldn't either of "remove/install" "reinstall" replace/overwrite any of the existing files?

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
rpm -V gstreamer.i686
```

returns

```
missing /usr/bin/gst-inspect-0.10
missing /usr/bin/gst-launch-0.10
missing /usr/bin/gst-typefind-0.10
missing /usr/bin/gst-xmlinspect-0.10
missing /usr/bin/gst-mxllaunch-0.10
missing /usr/libexec/gstreamer-0.10/gst-plugin-scanner
```

and `rpm -qc gstreamer.i686` returns nothing.

Note that`/usr/libexec/gstreamer-0.10/` is created on reinstall but "gst-plugin-scanner" is not installed.

**EDIT #2**
Installing gstreamer.x86_64 does restore the files, however, the reason why I deleted these files is because I am using gstreamer with a 32bit java project (again due to constraints). the problem is that `gst-plugin-scanner` installed by the 64-bit installer causes arch clashes with the 32 bit plugins trying to be loaded from the java bindings. My current solution is to remove these "common files" and re-run the 32bit installer because I found the installer was not overwriting these common files.

Is there a way to force yum or rpm to do this? or even a more intuitive way to switch between 32/64bit version of gstreamer?

Comment: After you manually remove those files what does `rpm -V gstreamer.i686` say? What does `rpm -qc gstreamer.i686` list? `yum remove && yum install` should absolutely bring the files back though if they are in that package. What OS and version of the package are you working with?

Comment: @EtanReisner: see edits. rpm verify acknowledges the missing files but they are still not being reinstalled.

Comment: What does `rpm -qf /usr/bin/gst-inspect-0.10` say? Can you get the `yum -d10` (very verbose) output from attempting the reinstall and clean install?

Comment: @EtanReisner: `rpm -qf /usr/bin/gst-inspect-0.10` returns gstreamer-0.10-7.el7.x86_64; the 64bit version and not the 32? `yum -d10` just lists "looking for dependencies..." and not much else.

Comment: I meant the output from `yum -d10` on the reinstall and clean install commands you were trying. And I wondered if this was a multi-lib issue. I'm impressed EL7 managed to get multilib binaries to work. Anyway, that's the issue. EL7 doesn't think it needs to install the binaries again for that package because they are shadowed by the binaries for the x86_64 package. Try this with that one and I bet it works as expected.

Comment: @EtanReisner: see edits again. maybe you can point me in a better direction :)

Comment: I have no idea what the multilib support for this sort of thing is on EL7. You'd have to check the docs to see if there was a way to manually pick which "wins". Alternatively if you don't want or need the 64bit version then just uninstall that package. You could also manually extract the 32bit files from the RPM and use them from some other path explicitly (assuming the libraries/plugins/etc. for both are set up correctly).

Comment: @EtanReisner: I swear this "remove common file/reinstall desired arch" method worked last week. At any rate I will add the manual rpm extraction to this method to ensure those common files are correct. Thanks for your help!